# How to read parquet files using pyspark when paths are listed in a dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe which contains list of 1M s3 paths something like below:

input_df_s3_path

```
|path                    |
--------------------------
S3://abcbucket/fhg.parquet
s3://abcbucket/gbj.parquet
```

I want to read all of these parquet files in an efficient way considering large data volume.

This is how I am doing this:

```
input_df_s3_path = spark.read.csv("s3a://bucketname/s3_path.csv")
    s3_paths = input_df_s3_path.select('path').rdd.map(lambda row : row[0]).collect()
    input_df = sqlContext.read.parquet(*s3_paths)
```

Is there any other way so that I can read the files in more efficient and faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One fairly efficient way is to first store all the paths in a .csv file.

Then access that file.

Rather than calling:`

```
sqlContext.read.parquet(*s3_paths)
```

You can store the paths and then access them.

It will reduce the overhead of calling sqlContext.read.parguet() method again and again.

You can use:

```
 df = spark.read.parquet("/path/to/infile.parquet")
 df.write.csv("/path/to/outfile.csv")
```

Refer to these links for more information on making the process more efficient:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/64449/how-to-move-compressed-parquet-file-using-adf-or-d.html
2. https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-use-Spark-to-read-a-whole-directory-instead-of-a-single-file

Comment: That's what I am using. I have a csv file where all the s3 paths is stored, creating a dataframe from that csv file, converting all s3 paths in a list and passing that list to read.parquet(). Updated the code snippet. Is this what you suggested?

Answer (score 1):

Just something I recently came across:

`.rdd.map(lambda row : row[0]).collect()` is very slow since it creates a udf and loops over all of the rows in the dataframe.

Much faster for me was using a list comprehension:

`[row.path for row in input_df_s3_path.select('path').collect()]`